# Find all the words in a string that match multiple array keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like `array("red","blue","azure"...)` and i have a string that might contain some of the words. The task is to get array of all the matching colors from the given string.

String example: "Red fox met a blue whale". It should output ["red","blue"]

Give me a starting point to go on with.

Thanks,
Martti

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[str_word_count()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) with a `format` argument of `1` or `2`, then an [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).... but watch out for case-sensitivity, force it all to lower case first

```
$matchWords = array("red","blue","azure");
$sentence = "Red fox met a blue whale";

$result = array_intersect(
    $matchWords,
    str_word_count(strtolower($sentence), 1)
);

var_dump($result);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/f5Z0Xp)

Comment: that did the job, but so did the previus. Why is thisone better?

Answer (score 1):

If you put all the values that you are looking for into an array, using '|' as a delimiter, you can use this in a regex to match all values.

```
$valsArray = implode('|',$vals);

preg_match_all('/($valsArray)/',$string,$matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<?php

$array1=array("red","blue","azure") ;
$str="red fox met a blue whale";
$str=explode(" ",$str);

echo $array1[0];
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array1);$i++){
 
 if (in_array($array1[$i],$str)){
$words[]=$array1[$i];

}

 }
print_r($words)

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I figured out I need it to be more complex. Is it possible to do it like that:

1) Let's find all the colors from the string that are present in the array 2) Translate the colors to other language using another array

original array ["red","blue","green"] translated array ["punane","sinine","roheline"]

So from "Red fox met a blue whale" I need to get ["punane","sinine"]

Thanks, Martti

Answer (score 0):

guys.

This is the code to translate filtered items using matching translated array

```
  foreach($filteredArray as $key => $value) {
      $myTranslatedColors[] = $translatedArray[$key]; 
    }
```

Thank you all.